# R studio warnings appearing upside down

Tags: r, rstudio

For some reason my warnings in Rstudio are appearing upside down. Some of the system messages when I commit to github are also upside down. You should be able to see the issue in the attached screenshot.

Any ideas how to fix this? I've restarted the r session, but that didn't do anything.

[image: Image of upside down warnings in Rstudio]

Comment: Did you notice this only once

Comment: seeing today's date ... could it be you're posting from a more eastwards timezone? ;-)

Comment: You might have better luck posting to the[ RStudio Community forum](https://community.rstudio.com/c/rstudio-ide/9). [This post from that forum may be pertinent](https://community.rstudio.com/t/install-r-studio-on-win8-my-studio-is-upside-down/80325)